# UITableViewCell animation while scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, animation, scroll

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells in it. These cells can be opened and closed with an animation. When the user scrolls I would like to close the cell. I do this by posting a notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"closeSwipedCell" object:nil];
```

This will call a method which does my simple animation in my subclass of UITableViewCell. This is working fine but the animation won't happen until the user stops scrolling the UITableView again.
Is it possible to do this animation while scrolling the table view?

Comment: I know, that, for example, if there is UIWebView in cell loading some picture then while table view is scrolling, the picture won't appear even if it was already loaded.

Comment: Why are you using notifications? have you tried to call the cell animation method directly from the scroll view delegate (UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass)? consider that notifications are not send immediately but coalesced for the next run loop, so it could be that during the scrolling no messages are sent and then this explains the delay with the animation. This is just a guess

Comment: Notifications might not be the most elegant solution but it seems the simplest as I would have to store the active cell and call that on scroll to avoid using notifications. It seems that the notification is sent right away as the cell does start the animation. When opened the cell will be slided to the right (a bit like Tweetie/Twitter), then when closing it will do a little bounce animation. It does close but does not make the little "bounce" animation which it will do if I call the method without scrolling (e.g. swiping the cell again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great detailed explanation of how to do a swipe to a cell submenu, like the twitter iphone app. I think it's very similar to what your looking for.  It doesn't use notifications to close a cell, it uses the events from the UIScrollViewDelegate as the other commenters have recommended.

[iDevRecipes](http://idevrecipes.com/)
look for the post on idevrecipes.com called "How does the Twitter iPhone app implement side swiping on a table".

There's good description but also code to download.

Comment: That's a way better implementation than my one. It didn't even occur to me to use the UITableView for detecting swipes and so on. Instead I was detecting the swipes on a subclass of UITableViewCell. That's a lot more hassle. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll:` and fire your event then.

Check out the [Apple docs on UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).

EDIT: If I was unclear, the `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to the `UISCrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. When my table view closes it will create a "bounce effect". I achieve this effect by sliding a subview inside the UITableViewCell subclass back and fourth a couple of times but this won't happen until the user stops scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollViewDidScroll:` may only be called at the end of the user scrolling. You may want to try firing your notification using the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` delegate method, which will definitely be called at the beginning of the scroll action.

There are also several `UIViewAnimationOptions` constants (IIRC, `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` is the one I'm thinking of) that affect whether animation will begin during another animation action, such as scrolling (tracking).

You'll need to `OR` that option with your existing animation options in the `options:` parameter of your animation method call.